# ActiveMQ - keep consumed messages until it's acknowledge to delete

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I have an Spring Boot app that is listening to a ActiveMQ queue.

Is there a way to tell ActiveMQ to keep consumed messages until it's received acknowledgement to delete the message from my service?

My scenario is I read message from queue and once consumed, I'm sending it to an external queue. If the external service fails to process the message, I would loose the message. Is there away I can tell active mq to hold onto consumed message until it's received an acknowledgement to delete.

Answer (score 1):

The safest option would be to use an XA transaction to perform the consume/send atomically (assuming the broker where you're sending the message supports XA). I'm not sure how easy or hard that is in Spring, but I know it's pretty simple in a Java EE container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the individual acknowledge mode which ack the single message. Below is the code for same:

```
    import javax.jms.Connection;
    import javax.jms.JMSException;

    import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
    import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer;
    import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession;
    import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTextMessage;

    public class SimpleConsumer {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
            Connection conn = null;
            try {
                ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
                conn = cf.createConnection("consumer", "consumer");
                ActiveMQSession session = (ActiveMQSession) conn.createSession(false,
                        ActiveMQSession.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                ActiveMQMessageConsumer consumer = (ActiveMQMessageConsumer) session
                        .createConsumer(session.createQueue("QUEUE"));
                conn.start();
                ActiveMQTextMessage msg = null;
                while ((msg = (ActiveMQTextMessage) consumer.receive()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Received message is: " + msg.getText());
               // Call your service and ack the message if successfully processed                    
                 msg.acknowledge();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    try {
                        conn.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The author's original problem is around message "loss" when the consumed message is acknowledged but the sent message fails. This solution opens the door to the opposite problem where the message can be sent successfully but fails to be acknowledged (e.g. due to network outage) which leads to redelivery and duplicate messages sent.  If sending the message is idempotent then that's not a problem, but if it is the the consumer needs to be able to detect duplicates or the whole process needs to be atomic (e.g. using XA).